# Get Branches and Merges history in TFS API (TFS 2008, VS 2012)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge, branching-and-merging

I use *VS 2012, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll 11.0* (TFS API) and server *TFS 2008*.

I have create Branch

```
int changesetId = vcServer.CreateBranch(sourcePath, targetPath, VersionSpec.Latest);
Changeset changeset = vcServer.GetChangeset(changesetId);
            changeset.Comment = comment;
            changeset.Update();
```

I can get Changeset list

```
      var ChangesetList = vcServer.QueryHistory(targetPath,
              VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, "", versionFrom, VersionSpec.Latest,
              Int32.MaxValue,
              true, // the boolean "include changes" is taking the time... If you do not include the changes and only the metadata of the changesets the query is very fast
              false).Cast<Changeset>();
```

I can do Checkout and Checkin about files in Branch, and then do Merges.

I'm confused how get good information about branches history (`GetBranchHistory` ), merges history (maybe `QueryMergesWithDetails`), and differences with `QueryPendingSets`.

Answer (score 1):

I think old, old blog post by Robert may help you
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roberthorvick/archive/2006/02/04/524960.aspx
If memory serves we added much better api in TFS 2010 to support more robust annotate and branch visualization.
As for QueryPendingSets, it is not related to branch history. It gives you possible sets of pending changes on the server. You can also try Workspace.GetPendingChanges but I would need to know specifics to help :)